# MySQL Count Where Clause Issue

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP form that has 3 drop-downs which enables the user to select parameters to be passed to a MySQL select statement. I want to return the total number of records dependant on the criteria selected.

The problem I have is that the result returns several totals instead of a grand total.

> SELECT distinct count(membership_type) as total FROM members_main
>   where membership_status like '%' and membership_type like '%' and
>   200_member like '%' group by membership_type

Can anyone help?

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT count(membership_type) as total FROM members_main where membership_status like '%' and membership_type like '%' and 200_member like '%'`

Don't use group by. When you use group by clause you are getting count for each `membership_type` that is why you are getting multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

`count(membership_type)` will give only one value you can not use `distinct`